# How to display a confirmation message like "Deleted"

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to display a confirmation message after a choice in the menu.

For example if you want to delete an image in the Timeline, you tap on the glass to open the menu, you select "Delete", you have a progression bar to cancel if you want, when the progressbar is complete a kind of toast appear to say "Deleted" and disappear.

I would like to reproduce only the "Deleted" part but I've searched everywhere and cannot find a way to do it. Is there an API or should I manually implement it with a layout containing the text wanted and display it for 3 seconds... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for this to work you will need to build a layout and then set it as the current view using setContentView for a specific amount of time and then return to your main view.